# Get the return Type for inherited generic method

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have these 3 classes

```
public class Box<O> {

    public O getItem() {...}

}
```

```
public class CoolBox extends Box<Integer> { ... }
```

```
public class AmazingBox extends CoolBox { ... }
```

At one point in my code, I need to get the return Type of the method `getItem()` for the `AmazingBox` class, but when accessing its methods via reflection, I get `Object` as the return Type instead of `Integer`.

Is there any way, (plain java or extra libraries) to get `Integer` as the return Type?

This is the code I used to get the return type:

```
Class<?> c = AmazingBox.class;  // This is not how i get the class but its for demonstration purposes

Method m = c.getMethod("getItem");

Type t = m.getReturnType();
```

Comment: Can you show the code you used to get `O`?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, what I get is `Object` class. I added code anyways. The thing is that I don't know how to get `Integer`

Comment: I don't think you can get `Integer`, as generics is only a compile time thing. You _can_ get `Integer` if `AmazingBox` or `CoolBox` overrides the method though.

Comment: You get `Object` because the real returned type is `Object`, that mechanism is called *type erasure* which means that after having verified the correctness of the typing the compiler emits a code in which types disappeared. Generics are just compile-time constructs.

Comment: Try `getGenericReturnType()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just discovered that there is a library called [GenericsResolver](https://github.com/xvik/generics-resolver) that does exactly what I want.

Using this piece of code it returns the correct type

```
Class<?> clazz = AmazingBox.class;
GenericsContext genericsContext = GenericsResolver.resolve(clazz);
Method method = clazz.getMethod("getItem");
Type methodReturnType = genericsContext.method(method).resolveReturnType();
```

Answer (score 1):

While inheriting you can use generics for inheriting classes and create lower or upper bounds accordingly. If you don't do that assume you are working without using generics and won't get type safety on inheriting non-generic classes.

In short, if you go hybrid, `type erasures` will become effective with following rules (ref- oracle documentation)

> ## Type Erasure
>
> Generics were introduced to the Java language to provide tighter type checks at compile time and to support generic programming. To implement generics, the Java compiler applies type erasure to:
>
> - Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or Object if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.
> - Insert type casts if necessary to preserve type safety.
> - Generate bridge methods to preserve polymorphism in extended generic types.
>
> Type erasure ensures that no new classes are created for parameterized types; consequently, generics incur no runtime overhead.