# Generic type is lost once parent class has generic

Tags: java, generics

I have a class like below. My question is once i put generic type on the parent class , it will cause compilation error on "nested" attributes builder i have. If i remove generic type in the parent class it works fine. any idea how to overcome this ?

```
package com.mlp.raptor.cmf;

import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class Builder<T extends Builder>{

    public T newattr(String value){
        return (T)this;
    }

    public static class subBuilder{

        public subBuilder attrraw(String value){
            return this;
        }

    }

    public T subList(Consumer<subBuilder>... value){
        return (T)this;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)throws Exception{
        Consumer<subBuilder> s = d -> d.attrraw("dd");
        new Builder().newattr("test").subList(s);
        new Builder().subList(z -> z.attrraw("dd")); //compile issue
    }

}
```

Comment: my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58482157/get-the-return-type-for-inherited-generic-method/58483849#58483849 should help

Answer (score 0):

You are using a raw instance of `Builder`, the diamond should help here:

```
new Builder<>().subList(z -> z.attrraw("dd"));
           ↑↑
```

Now you should be getting some compiler warnings, but that's another thing, which could be easily resolved by carefully defining type-parameters.

Comment: That doesnt work if i do this  new Builder2<>().newattr("d").subList(z -> z.attrraw("dd")); //compile issue

Comment: Well, it's a completely different statement. Maybe you should read some structured tutorial on Generics to get better insight.